# Erro de duplicidade de pacote ao atualizar ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

No ubuntu 14.04, estou tentando atualizar os repositorios com apt-get update. Porém, para no erro de duplicidade abaixo.
Estou fazendo o procedimento para instalar o phpmyadmin.
Desde já agradeço pela ajuda.

```
# apt-get update
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                              
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                                  
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                      
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease                       
Get:1 http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg [72 B]                       
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                      
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg [933 B]           
Get:3 http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg [198 B]                          
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release [58,5 kB]             
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease                      
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                    
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release                                    
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease                    
Get:5 http://dl.google.com stable Release [1.347 B]                            
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                               
Hit http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                            
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Get:6 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg [933 B]          
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Get:7 http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages [1.240 B]                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Get:8 http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages [1.220 B]                 
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources [30,6 kB]        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages                            
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages                             
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Get:10 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release.gpg [933 B]       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Sources [14 B]    
Hit http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release                                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Get:12 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources [6.808 B]   
Get:13 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release [58,5 kB]           
Get:14 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Sources [688 B]   
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US                     
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages [105 kB] 
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Get:16 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release [58,6 kB]         
Hit http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                           
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_US                         
Get:17 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages [14 B]
Hit http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources                     
Hit http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources                       
Get:18 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages [35,9 kB]
Hit http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Sources                     
Hit http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                    
Hit http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages              
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                            
Hit http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages       
Get:19 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [1.157 B]
Hit http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages              
Get:20 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages [102 kB]  
Hit http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                     
Hit http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages               
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_US                         
Get:21 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages [14 B]
Hit http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages                 
Hit http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages               
Get:22 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages [35,9 kB]
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                            
Get:23 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages [1.392 B]
Get:24 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en [49,4 kB]
Hit http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                    
Hit http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en              
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en       
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en_US                     
Hit http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en              
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en                
Get:25 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources [80,4 kB]      
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en_US                     
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en       
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Get:26 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Sources [14 B]   
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en_US                     
Get:27 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources [60,1 kB]  
Get:28 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en [19,5 kB]
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Get:29 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Sources [2.681 B]
Get:30 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages [214 kB]
Get:31 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [14 B]
Get:32 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages [154 kB]
Get:33 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [7.397 B]
Get:34 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages [210 kB] 
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en_US          
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en_US    
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en_US    
Get:35 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages [14 B]
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en_US      
Get:36 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages [154 kB]
Get:37 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [7.569 B]
Get:38 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en [97,4 kB]
Hit http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en      
Hit http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en      
Get:39 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en [74,5 kB]
Get:40 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Sources [14 B]       
Get:41 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Sources [14 B] 
Get:42 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Sources [7.265 B]
Get:43 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Sources [768 B]
Get:44 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages [14 B]
Get:45 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted amd64 Packages [14 B]
Get:46 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe amd64 Packages [8.141 B]
Get:47 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages [619 B]
Get:48 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main i386 Packages [14 B] 
Get:49 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted i386 Packages [14 B]
Get:50 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe i386 Packages [8.157 B]
Get:51 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse i386 Packages [619 B]
Hit http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-en          
Hit http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en    
Hit http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en    
Get:52 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-en [5.273 B]
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US                 
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_US           
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_US           
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_US             
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en_US         
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en_US   
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en_US   
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en_US     
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-en_US       
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en_US 
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en_US 
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-en_US   
Fetched 1.663 kB in 1min 44s (15,9 kB/s)                                       
Reading package lists... Done
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_talkplugin_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_talkplugin_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb/ stable/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_talkplugin_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-i386_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb/ stable/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_talkplugin_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

Segue meu arquivo /etc/apt/sources.list

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140417)]/ trusty main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb-src http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça um backup da lista do apt-get:

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.bak
```

Depois disso remova as linhas duplicadas listadas acima:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Rode novamente `sudo apt-get update`

Qualquer coisa volte novamente o backup:

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list.bak /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Comment: Atualizei o post com o arquivo source.list. Não tem o talkplugin. Que é o que acusado como duplicado.

Comment: confira na pasta /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ se tem alguma lista do google, caso tenha mais de uma lista apague esta: rm -rf /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list